# How to use promise.all in a scenario like this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I have three or four functions returning promises in the following fashion:

```
function foo(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        //do some work
        return resolve();
        //some condition
        return reject();
    })
}
```

So what I have is three or four foo-type functions, let's say I add these functions in an array called `functionArray` like this:

```
functionArray.push(foo1, foo2, foo3)
```

What would be the way to use `Promise.all` in this scenario? I would like to achieve something like this:

```
Promise.all(functionArray).then(() => {
    console.log(done)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Promise.all`](https://www.google.com/search?q=Promise.all&oq=Promise.all&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i61l2j0l2.1870j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) takes array of Promises and not functions that return promises, `functionArray.push(foo1(),foo2(),foo3())` will work.

Also `.then` callback will return the response

```
Promise.all(functionArray).then((response)=>{
   console.log('done' , response)
})
```

Comment: This works, thanks.

Comment: Glad to have helped :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can read in detail about `Promise.all` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

The Promise.all(iterable) method returns a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved or when the iterable argument contains no promises. It rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects.

```
functionArray.push(foo(), foo1(), foo2())
Promise.all(functionArray).then((done)=>{
    console.log(done)
})

//here functionArray is array of promises, and done is array of response from those promises in similar order.
```

Also your function `foo` is not a promise. Return of `foo()` is a promise. So functionArray should contain promises.